# Lightning - Access to the elements of a table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, table

I have a table, and I want access to value of the columns:

- I want sum all rows (fields Item_1__c, Item_2__c, Item_3__c,
  Item_4__c of all rows) and set to variable totalColumns.
- And addClass to row if the sumColumn of this row is greater than 50
  (example, if row1 --> Item_1__c + Item_2__c + Item_3__c + Item_4__c >
  50 ; addClass "moreHours").

I dont know how to access the value of the elements in the table.
Thanks

Component:

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />

<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="totalColumns" type="decimal" default="0"/>

TOTAL: {!v.totalColumns}
<div class="slds" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" aura:id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label" aura:id="tr_myTable">
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Account Name">
                    <div>Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item1">
                    <div>Item 1</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item2">
                    <div>Item 2</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item3">
                    <div>Item 3</div>
                </th>      
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item4">
                    <div>Item 4</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">     
                <tr aura:id="tr_myTable">
                    <td data-label="Name" title="Name">
                        <div><a data-record="{!account.Id}" onclick="{!c.redirectToSobject}">{!account.Name}</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Account Number">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Item_1__c}" change="{!calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Account Number">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Item_2__c}" change="{!calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Account Number">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Item_3__c}" change="{!calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td> 
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Account Number">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Item_4__c}" change="{!calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.THIS.moreHours{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: How would you sum a row? each column could have different data types. I see name as one of column. Please update your question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I need: Sum all rows of the table (number values), and validate if the 4values os each row is greater than 50 (in this case addClass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use ternary operator to add class based on sum of
   rows.

**class="{!account.row1 + account.row2 gt 50 ? 'moreHours' : ''}"**

2. To update totalColumns to sum of all rows. Recalculate sum of all rows on change of input and assign to totalColumns attribute.

Refere below code I have tried it for 2 rows. you add your rows as per requirement.

**Component :**

```
        <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalColumns" type="decimal" default="0"/>

    TOTAL: {!v.totalColumns}
<div class="slds" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" aura:id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label" aura:id="tr_myTable">
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Account Name">
                    <div>Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item1">
                    <div>Item 1</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item2">
                    <div>Item 2</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">     
                <tr aura:id="tr_myTable" class="{!account.NumberOfEmployees + account.Contact_Count__c gt 50 ? 'moreHours' : ''}">
                    <td data-label="Name" title="Name">
                        <div><a data-record="{!account.Id}" onclick="{!c.redirectToSobject}">{!account.Name}</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Account Number">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.NumberOfEmployees}" change="{!c.calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Account Number">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Contact_Count__c}" change="{!c.calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

**JS Controller :**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper)
    {
        var action1 = cmp.get("c.getAccounts");
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS' && response.getReturnValue()) {
               cmp.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action1);
    },
    calculateSum : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var total = 0;
        var accList = cmp.get("v.accounts");
        for(var i = 0; i < accList.length; i++) {
            if(!isNaN(accList[i].NumberOfEmployees)) {
                total += accList[i].NumberOfEmployees;    
            }
            if(!isNaN(accList[i].Contact_Count__c)) {
                total += accList[i].Contact_Count__c;
            }

        }
        cmp.set("v.totalColumns", total);
    }
})
```

Comment: It works corrrectly, its very easy, thanks
and please, how can I add a style in a specific row?

Comment: @juan Manual Garcia If it works for you then you can accept answer, so that it will be useful for others.

Comment: Please, I asked 2 questions in the post, the first is OK, could you tell me how add styles please?

Comment: I have added answer for both. check  <tr aura:id="tr_myTable" class="{!account.NumberOfEmployees + account.Contact_Count__c gt 50 ? 'moreHours' : ''}">.In  this line of code you replace your rows instead of account.NumberOfEmployees and other fields.

Comment: @Amit - 'Check this code' is not very instructive for others to learn, pelase include a detailed description of what it is the code does and how it addresses the OP's question(s). thanks

Comment: @glls Answer updated.